# Какой запрос sql надо прописать чтобы найти время вылета

Tags: sql

Есть бд access авиабилеты, в ней есть таблица рейсы.

В рейсах есть поля:

- Город Вылета,
- Дата Вылета,
- Время Вылета.

| Город Вылета | Дата Вылета | Время Вылета |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Казань | 06.06.22 | 07:00 |
| Казань | 12.06.22 | 12:00 |

Какой запрос надо прописать, чтобы выходило:

```
Время Вылета 7:00,
```

Если я указываю:

```
Город Вылета: Казань, 
Дата Вылета: 06.06.22.
```

( Скорее всего вопрос глупый, но я не знаю как правильно его найти в интернете )

Comment: Вы что то пытались прописать? Что пробовали?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: tym32167, Дело в том, что я новичок, а сам sql особо не знаю, те запросы, которые я в основном использовал не подходят в данной ситуации, соответственно особо путного ничего и не прописывал. Дело в том, что у меня есть две формы. Форма1 откуда берутся данные, при выборе Казань -> Наб_Челны с выбором даты 06.06.22, есть кнопка путь обратно, когда её включаешь во второй форме появляется города наоборот Наб_Челны -> Казань, только во второй форме дата должна не выбираться, а сразу выходить из данных бд, в данном случае дата 12.06.22

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-where-clause.htm#:~:text=The%20SQL%20WHERE%20clause%20is,fetching%20only%20the%20necessary%20records. Инфа по SELECT

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119369/simple-datetime-sql-query Подобный вопрос

Comment: Frehzy, спасибо большое

Comment: вот такой запрос должен быть: `select ... from ... where ...=... and ...=...`,  а вот вместо троеточия попробуй сам подставить нужные данные